# Statically allocate array with struct containing a string

Tags: arrays, string, rust, static, allocation

I am writing a program that has an array which size I know, it is a fixed instruction set. Each entry in the array maps to an struct of the opcode and some metadata, such as the function that implements the opcode and its name, a String.

I need to allocate the array before I actually compute and fill the instruction set on each opcode.

Rust won't let me allocate such array statically, even if I know the size and when the initialized state does NOT require ANY pointers, as I would like all strings to be empty, which means no allocations and you could have a "zero value" of the string that is preferably fine to be copied.

Any suggestions? Is there anyway to do it?
Seems Rust really likes to you use a Vec for everything? Even when static memory, which should be preferable on a non GC program language, would have been possible in many cases such as this? This is confusing.

Comment: Please include the code that isn't working in a MRE.

Comment: You can create an array of structs with strings statically: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=744d6ccf2bf6b4a6bcced9f8f4a29d17). Please provide a concrete example that you're having problems with since, from my understanding, what you're asking about is certainly possible.

Comment: Or `const EMPTY: Instruction = Instruction { name: String::new() }; static ARRAY: [Instruction; 5] = [EMPTY; 5];`, or on nightly `static ARRAY: [Instruction; 5] = [const { Instruction { name: String::new() } }; 5];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/array-expr.html#array-expressions):

> If the length operand has a value greater than 1 then this requires that the type of the repeat operand is `Copy` or that it must be a path to a constant item.

Therefore, to initialize an array using `[VALUE; NUM]` syntax, either the type implements the `Copy` trait or that `VALUE` is a `const`.

As pointed out by Chayim Friedman, you can use code like below:

```rust
const EMPTY: Instruction = Instruction { name: String::new() };
static ARRAY: [Instruction; 5] = [EMPTY; 5];
```

However, if you are working with a fixed set of data, it might be easier to just populate the list with predefined names, using `&'static str`.

If there is a need to create an array from a value that cannot be made to a constant and is not `Copy`, you can use `std::array::from_fn` like so:

```rust
let value = String::new();
let array: [_; 6] = std::array::from_fn(|_| value.clone());
```